# How can polling be faster than interupt

Tags: interrupt, polling

I'm trying to learn interrupts by reading [these slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~demke/469F.06/Lectures/Lecture6.pdf) and am wondering, why can polling be faster than interrupts? If a device has a direct wire to the CPU that it can use to signal an interrupt, I can't imagine something being faster than that.

> Give each device a wire (interrupt line) that it can use to signal the
>   processor 
>   • When interrupt signaled, processor executes a routine
>   called an interrupt handler to deal with the interrupt

(does it litterally mean a wire by the way?)

> Polling can be better if processor has to respond to an event ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupt handling, needs context switching (pipeline break, save stack pointer, CPU registers, etc..) before servicing the interrupt, which needs some time (dependent on the architecture). Polling can be faster if it's the only task (keep polling for the event), as you stay in the same context. In this case, it's only the poll + loop instructions time.

Comment: Oh I see, so an interrupt always requires the OS to intervene and dispatch the interrupt handler, where as if the program directly builds polling into itself then a new program doesn't need to be swapped into the CPU. Is that the gist of it?

Comment: Yes, and no. Generally the CPU execute some code by itself on interrupt. Sometime this code is part of the OS, sometime not. Depend on your OS, architecture and interrupt. But in all case there are some low-level stuff to care about before doing the actual job.